# the way to mock module

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I am using mock 1.0.1. I have almost found the way to mock everything. It is a powerful tool.

I have all my configuration in a module called algo_config.

The structure roughly as follows:

```
--text
----algo_config
```

I have tried

```
with patch('text.algo_config') as Mockconfig:
    ....
```

But it gives me an error says basically text module do not have attribute algo_config, it seems that a module can not be mocked in this way.

Is there any way to mock a module directly instead of mock each attributes and functions, classes of it one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the problem here is that patching overrides names, not values. If one module does `import text.algo_config`, it now has a local name called `text.algo_config` that points to the module, but is completely unrelated to the name used in other modules. They just named the same. (That's why `import foo as bar` works – it's just names.) Patching another reference to that module won't affect this reference.

You have two options. Either you patch the module reference or you affect future imports.

The solution you most likely want is the former. You do not patch the module, but the reference to the module you care about. For example, say you are testing `frobnicator.py`. That module does `from text import algo_config`. You can then use `with patch('frobnicator.algo_config') as algo_config` and that will affect all uses of `algo_config` within `frobnicator`.

Alternatively, you can also put a mock into `sys.modules`, which will affect *future* `import` statements. That is, any import statements already run will have the old value imported; and any import statements run during this patch's existence will import the mocked object, but not revert to the real module. This is incredibly fickle and likely not what you want.